# NLTK Tree Format is not as docs show it

Tags: python, nltk

On the NLTK docs, this is how printing a tree (in this case, 'entities') is shown to be:

```
import nltk
sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
Arthur didn't feel very good."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
entities = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)

entities
Tree('S', [('At', 'IN'), ('eight', 'CD'), ("o'clock", 'JJ'),
           ('on', 'IN'), ('Thursday', 'NNP'), ('morning', 'NN'),
       Tree('PERSON', [('Arthur', 'NNP')]),
           ('did', 'VBD'), ("n't", 'RB'), ('feel', 'VB'),
           ('very', 'RB'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')])
```

But when I try to do the exact same thing with the exact same code, this is what happens:

```
entities
(S
  At/IN
  eight/CD
  o'clock/NN
  on/IN
  Thursday/NNP
  morning/NN
  (PERSON Arthur/NNP)
  did/VBD
  n't/RB
  feel/VB
  very/RB
  good/JJ
  ./.)
```

In case you haven't caught on, I would like the output of my code (which is the exact same code) to be formatted like the output of the code from the docs.

I have tried this on both python 2.7 and python 3.5, with the same results. Is there a fix? Perhaps I'm just missing some nltk add-on? If there is a fix, I'd prefer python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you just typed `entities` to get the result you report? What you see in the nltk homepage is the unambiguous representation of the tree object (its “[repr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#repr)” form, in python terms). You get when you dump a variable by just typing its name at the prompt. If you print out the tree with `print(entities)` (which is probably what you actually did), it provides the customized, more readable form without the `Tree` types and tuple notation.

So there is no problem, and no fix is needed. These are two representations of the same object. If you have to use `print` to see the variable's content (e.g., you are not at the interactive prompt) but you want to match the output you see in the example, you can use `print(repr(entities))`.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that, and yes you were right -- I typed "print(entities)" to get my output.